# What is the distance between binary planets?

Tags: planets, distance

What should be the distance between two Earth-like binary planets, each having its own moon? Each planet is rotating about a barycenter in a plane of their solar system and the moons are rotating around each planet perpendicular to the plane of the solar system.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. You might find useful [this page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to understand which questions are on topic here. Aside from fixing the all caps, which is widely recognized as rude while posting on the internet, can you also provide more information to better define your problem?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Please ntoe that you should be careful about phrasing and presenting your question in a clear and easy to understand way. Using Caps Lock is like screaming at us, which is very likely to result in negative feelings in the reader. Please make it easy for the people you are asking for help to help you by making it easy to read your question. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I'm seeing this in the re-open queue.  I don't see enough information to answer the  question. If you asked for a _minimum_ distance, that could be answerable, but 'what should be the distance' is mostly opinion based.

Comment: @kingledion's right.  Asteroids prove that any distance could be used.  We need to know about the star, the distance of the planets from the star, the size of the moons, etc.  And shooting for the minimum rather than "any" would make a big difference.  At this time there is no single "right" answer.

Comment: "moons rotating around each planet perpendicular to the plane of the solar system"? My intuition might be wrong, but in a binary planet, that sounds very unstable, if two planets are orbiting around each other, the natural thing for their moons (in the rare case they have any) would be to fall in the same plane, since the forces of both planets are acting on them.